# Get all possible array indices for value

Tags: php, arrays

Very simple question, I need to get all the indices of double dimension array (an external array consists of inner arrays) where a particular value is present in the inner array, i need index of external array or outer array.

Example of the array is below:
-> Other values ('othervalues') are very large strings, it would take time if I use them. I need efficient way.

```
<?php

    $array=array(array(0,'othervalues...','othervalues'),array(0,'othervalues...','othervalues'),array(2,'othervalues...','othervalues'),array(2,'othervalues...','othervalues'),array(3,'othervalues...','othervalues'));

?>
```

The output of above array should be array consisting of the indices found for that value.
I want to search value = 2 in the above array which is at index number 0 of every inner array.
So that would be an array of array(2,3), because value 2 is present at those indices of the external array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [**array_keys**](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function:

```
$index = array_keys($array, 2); // return array list
```

#### Result

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(12)
  [3]=>
  int(21)
  [4]=>
  int(32)
  [5]=>
  int(44)
  [6]=>
  int(51)
  [7]=>
  int(56)
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question, I am sorry but I wasn't able to figure out. Now I mentioned what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: @user1735921 But now you need `foreach` loop because of `multidimensional` array, is it OK for you?